# My decimal to binary converter gives wrong results with bigger numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've made a really simple decimal to binary converter, everything seems to work fine but when given a big number it spits out results that are way different from results from another online converters. I wonder why is that?

here's my code:

```
def main():
    numberstr = input("Number in decimal > ")
    number = int(numberstr)
    result = ""
    while number >= 1 == True:
        if (number % 2) == 1:
            remainder = "1"
            result = remainder + result
            if number == 1:
                number = 0
            else:
                number = number - 1
                number = number / 2
                number = int(number) 
                #^^^ this line is for getting rid of the float that comes from dividing.

        elif (number % 2) == 0:
            remainder = "0"
            result = remainder + result
            number = number / 2
            number = int(number)
        
    print(numberstr, "in binary is:", result)
  
main()
```

for example feeding it this number: 987654321987654321 
gives out this result: 110110110100110110100101111101111110111101000001001010000001 
While online converters (namely rapidtables.com and binaryhexconverter.com ) both give out this: 110110110100110110100101111101111110111101000001001010110001 
 
For comparing: 
110110110100110110100101111101111110111101000001001010000001 - my code
110110110100110110100101111101111110111101000001001010110001 
It seems that to some point it does the math right, but then it messes up for some reason. 
 Any ideas on what might be causing it?

Comment: There's no need for `== True:`. Just write `while number >= 1:`

Comment: You can use `number = number // 2` to do integer division. Then you don't have to subtract 1 or call `int()`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and try to [understand carefully what the code is actually doing](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) before asking for help finding a problem.

Comment: I assume this is an exercise, since in Python `format(987654321987654321,'b')` gives the same answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with division. When you do `number / 2` it becomes a float. When you are working with large numbers, floats will loose precision.

You need to use floor division `number // 2`, which gives the quotient of number divided by 2, discarding the remainder. Once you use floor division or integer division, you no longer need `number=number - 1`, or `number = int(number)`.

```
def main():
    numberstr = input("Number in decimal > ")
    number = int(numberstr)
    result = ""
    while number >= 1 == True:
        if (number % 2) == 1:
            remainder = "1"
            result = remainder + result
            if number == 1:
                number = 0
            else:
                number = number // 2
                #^^^ this line is for getting rid of the float that comes from dividing.

        elif (number % 2) == 0:
            remainder = "0"
            result = remainder + result
            number = number // 2
        
    print(numberstr, "in binary is:", result)
  
main()
```

This will give you the correct result:

```
110110110100110110100101111101111110111101000001001010110001
```

#### Alternatively,

Another good way of doing integer division by 2, i.e. discard the last binary digit, is to use bit shift operator `>>`, this shifts the binary representation to the right by 1 bit and thus removing the last bit, whether it's 0 or 1.

```
number = number >> 1
```

And to get the remainder, another good way is "bitwise and" operator `&`:

```
remainder_number = number & 1
```

Bitwise operations are fast.

So a much shorter version would be

```
def main():
    numberstr = input("Number in decimal > ")
    number = int(numberstr)
    result = ""
    while number >= 1:
        result = str(number & 1) + result
        number = number >> 1

    print(numberstr, "in binary is:", result)

main()
```

`if-else` statements are also slow, avoid them if you can.

Comment: There's no need for `number = number - 1` when you use integer division, since it rounds down.

Comment: great comment, fixed.

Comment: Stackoverflow guys being awesome as always. Thanks a lot!